# How to apply color to the images or objects which are above the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a colorful background. Over this background there is an white transparent image or white transparent color is applied which covers entire screen. What i need is, on top of this two i need to write text and this text color automatically should be replaced from the colorful background color which is behind the text as shown in the image below. Also the background color varies. How can i do this? I m sorry i m not giving any jsfiddle because i am not sure of how to do this.

[image]

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea on how to do this, hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) of some sort.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do this with JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657336/get-color-value-of-specific-position-in-colorbar-with-gradient

Comment: If you want to get help choosing a similar design that may work for your site, you might try http://ux.stackexchange.com/ or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution...

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    height: 100%; min-height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    /* Could be any background, including an image */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, green 0%, blue 50%, red 100%);
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); /* translucent white */
}
.text {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: 'Arial Black';
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    /* Same background as bg */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, green 0%, blue 50%, red 100%);
    /* The magic happens here... */
    -webkit-background-clip: text;    
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

...BUT it has the downside of **only working with webkit** at the moment.

- [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luken/gp65a/), but make sure you're in the latest Chrome.
- [Here's another example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) of using `background-clip` and `text-fill-color`.

Ultimately - unless this design is critical to your website - I would recommend that you *not* go with this method, and instead look for a more simple solution that will work cross-browser.

Comment: Yes, it is "only working with webkit" so it's not an optimal solution until/if the other browsers implement these style options. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to do what you want right now and have it work in all browsers.